# fabric - how to get host name while deploying

Tags: python, fabric

I have a fabfile

```
env.hosts = [
    # huge list, 80 hostnames
]
def dm():
    with cd('/home/project/application'):
        # how to get the actual hostname here, so I can run certain commands depending on hostname?
```

any ideas? fabric documentation gives me nothing on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access hostname using [`env.host`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#host).